# Retaining, Redirecting and Reloading

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a simple math quiz using PHP. It's meant to generate two random numbers for the user to multiply. If the user types in the **correct** answer, it's meant to redirect them to a congratulatory html page (using Header). However, if they get it **wrong**, the question is meant to change to a message stating so, and giving them another chance to answer it.

I've got everything to work so far, apart from one thing, which is retaining the question and answer after every incorrect submission. How can I stop this from happening? How do I stop the script from generating a new question/answer each time? I've used hidden text fields, but they didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Please, note that `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is vulnerable to code injection. Use something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code assumes you're passing $num1 and $num2 in $_POST, but there are no hidden fields for them:

```
<input type = "hidden" name = "num1" value="<?php echo $num1; ?>"/>
<input type = "hidden" name = "num1" value="<?php echo $num2; ?>"/>
```

Once you add these inputs, the question should appear correctly.

In order for the correct answer to be recorded, you need to take into account that the $answer variable currently stores the result of multiplying the random numbers, not the ones that were posted. You can try the following at the beginning of your code:

```
if (!isset($_POST['num1'])) {
  $num1 = Rand(1,10);
  $num2 = Rand(1,10);
} else  {
  $num1 =  $_POST['num1'];
  $num2 =  $_POST['num2'];
}
$answer = $num1 * $num2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I actually have those exact two lines in my current code, but I edited them out before submitting the code onto here and forgot to remove the corresponding POST code. Anyway, it still doesn't work either way.

Comment: What exactly is it that turns out to be wrong? Does it display the "you're wrong" message? Does it display the question with the old numbers? As said, I'd expect the answer input value to be wrong, since you're multiplying the randomly-generated $num1 and $num2 variables, not the posted ones.

Comment: "You're wrong.", is indeed displayed, and another chance is given to input the correct answer. But the script doesn't seem to store and compare the initial answer with the user's answer. So if the user types in the wrong answer the first time, then gets 'you're wrong', and tries to type in the answer again, the real (initial answer) has already changed since clicking submit. Basically, I need to prevent it from changing.

Comment: That's what I thought... I've edited my reply to fix the answer field.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But it doesn't seem to work. 'num1' and 'num2' come out as undefined and the answer is always stuck on 0.

Comment: Could you please post your full html? I'd like to see all the hidden fields. In the meantime, try using parseInt() around the numbers (see my edits).

Comment: I've edited my original post. I get a fatal error when running the script with the 'parseInt()' function.

Comment: Sorry about the parseInt(). That's JS! I've been working with PHP + JS all week and sometimes that happens. Anyway, I've edited my post. This time I actually tested it, and it works. Adding $_POST['num1'] specifically in the first line fixed it.